# ASP.NET rewrite rules in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, redirect

I was attempting to redirect

/KEY/TEXT
or

/KEY/WEB.ASPX

to redirector?key=KEY&url=TEXT or redirector?key=KEY&url=WEB.ASPX respectively.

I managed to gain success for /KEY in which I wrote the following in my web.config

```
<match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/redirector.aspx?key={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

however whichever way I attemped to match the URL for /TEXT or /WEB.ASPX I was not able to get.
I even attempted

```
<match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/redirector.aspx?key={R:1}&url={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Anyone could highlight what went wrong in the following request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/+([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/redirector.aspx?key={R:1}&amp;url={R:2}" />
```

See the differences

- – and . characters have to be escaped, because they are special characters
- You don't have to escape the following character /
- Each capture is required, so you can match `/KEY/TEXT` and ignore urls like `/KEY/`
- instead of &, use the xml entity `&amp;`

This is a rewrite rule, that means you would still see the url in browsers nav bar. If you want to redirect to redirector.aspx, then you have to use `type="Redirect"`